# Differences when convert between Geometry & Geography instances

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, geospatial

Using SQL Server 2008: assuming I have a valid geography object *geog1*, converting it to a geometry instance *geom1* (using the same SRID) and converting it back to an object geography *geog2* shows no difference between *geog1* and *geog2*.

However, due to a problem already discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1163925/sql-server-2008-geography-linestring-size-limitations) I cannot create a geography object containing a linestring from my original data. It works with geometry objects. However, if I perform a `MakeValid()` on the resulting geometry, I can create a geography object again.
The problem is that I don´t know if this geography will be much different compared to the original linestring that was not accepted by `geography::STGeomFromText()` before.
Especially the object length (`STLength()`) is of interest to me.

Does anyone know if the conversion between geography and geometry types is losless and if a `MakeValid()` call on a geometry changes the data (especially when it comes to length)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MakeValid(), by necessity, changes the underlying data of a geometry instance. (If it made no changes, then the resulting geometry would still be just as invalid as the original).

In many cases, the only change is to the *type* of the resulting geometry (i.e. an invalid, self-intersecting linestring may become a valid multilinestring), but it is also possible for coordinate values to change. However, these only shift by absolutely fractional amounts necessary to validate the geometry, and will not make a significant difference to the length.